# How do you cast an integer as a time in VHDL?

Tags: fpga, vhdl, programmable-logic

For the purposes of simplifying a test bench, I would like to set various delays by changing numerical values at the top of the file. I'd like to do something like:

```
input_frequency : integer := 1000000;
...
constant t_per : time := (1. / input_frequency * 1000000000.) ns;
```

... which does not compile.

Right now I'm hardcoding:

```
constant t_per : time := 1000 ns;
```

I have not been able to get the upper example to work using the *variable* keyword either.

Is there a way around hardcoding times in VHDL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

multiply (or operate otherwise) by the time unit

`constant t_per : time := (1 / input_frequency * 1000000000) * 1ns;` (or variations thereof)

Comment: Here is one reference that might help:  https://www.aldec.com/en/support/resources/documentation/articles/1165

Comment: Actually, the `1` before `ns` is not needed, but recommended good style. To get his code running, just the multiplication operator would be needed. There should be a delimiter (whitespace) between the integer value and the secondary unit (`ns`).

Comment: @CapnJJ Worked like a charm. Thanks. I did not quite understand how the fs/ns/ms/etc. keywords worked.

Comment: @Paebbels yep. I go back and forth between VHDL and Systemverilog, so syntax gets mashed for me at times :(   (I'll leave my answer that way so your comment still applies, for posterity sake)

Comment: @CapnJJ No complaints about your answer. I just wanted to add that fact :). Why use SV when you have VHDL? (but this question is of topic here ...)

Comment: @Paebbels I have focused on verification ~8 years and use SV for functional verification.  but, yeh, off-topic

Answer (score 4):

You can convert integer values to type time values. Each time value is represented as a position number on the number scale. Therefore, VHDL offers the attributes `'val(...)` and `'pos(...)`. Each integer unit represents one primary time unit. This primary unit is defined as femtosecond (fs). But many simulators like ModelSim chose a greater primary unit like picosecond (ps). You can set this *minimum time resolution limit* to femtoseconds with command line option `-t 1fs`.

Converting integers to time:

```
constant myInt  : integer := 10000;
constant myTime : time    := time'val(myInt);
```

This is equal to `10 ps`, because it's 10,000 fs. You can convert back with attribute `'pos` from a physical type value to a *universal integer* value.

The same can be achieved by multiplying time values with an integer, because package `std.standard` contains operator overloads for `*` to allow `time * integer` and `integer * time` operations.

```
constant myInt  : integer := 5;
constant myTime : time    := 10 ns * myInt;
```

This results in 50 ns. Of cause there are more operators overloaded like division or modulo.

---

If you like to play more with type time or experience other physical type like *frequency*, have a look at the [PoC Library](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC) and package [PoC.physical](https://github.com/VLSI-EDA/PoC/blob/master/src/common/physical.vhdl?ts=2).

Answer (score -2):

For people coming here from google, this answer is useful for convert frequency to time in test benches:

```
CONSTANT freq : positive := 50E6;
CONSTANT CLKPERIOD : time := (real(1E9)/real(freq)) * 1 ns;
```

The real() typecast allow more precise values.